# A basic notational doubt

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I have seen the following notation in a book for the continuous function $f$:

$f(.,.):\Bbb R^d \times \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous in the first argument on compacts w.r.t the second argument.

What is the meaning of it ? Is it that for a fixed $y$ 
the function 
$f(.,y): \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R$  is uniformly continuous on compacts i.e. a single $\delta$ works for "all" the compacts ?

So, for some other $y$, $\delta$ will be different.

The exact intercept from the paper: "$(y,z,x) \in S \times U \times \Bbb R^d \to p(dw|y,z,x) \in P(S)$ is continuous map. Moreover, the continuity in the $x$ variable is uniform on compacts w.r.t the other variables." $P(S)$ is the space of probability measures on a complete separable metric space $S$

Comment: It is sloppy wording, but I would guess that it means that for all compact sets $K$, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for all $y \in K$, if $\|x_1-x_2\| < \delta$, then $|f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @copper.hat: The exact intercept from the paper: "$(y,z,x) \in S \times U \times \Bbb R^d \to p(dw|y,z,x)$ is continuous map. Moreover, the continuity in the $x$ variable is uniform on compacts w.r.t the other variables."

Answer (score 1):

Every continuous function of two variables $f:X\times Y\to Z$ from (say Hausdorff) spaces into a metric space $Z$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets in the second argument when the first argument is held fixed. This means that the function $f_x:Y\to Z$ for fixed $x$ is uniformly continuous on each compact subset of $Y$ (which is true for any continuous function).

Comment: I have mentioned the exact intercept from the paper.

Comment: @user148951 I don't understand the excerpt from the paper. If you'd like I can delete my answer.